# Create Dockerfile for mongoDB 4.2 with authentication

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, authentication, dockerfile

how would you script the Dockerfile to create admin user for mongoDB 4.2 ?

Is there a one line command to create admin users not using an interactive subshell ? (didn't see any in mongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/))

Thanks for your help.

Passing MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD does not work anymore (removed from Docker hub mongo image [documentation](https://hub-stage.docker.com/_/mongo)).

The mongo Docker hub documentation only shows interactive shell admin user creation.

`> mongo admin`

executes mongo interactive shell but how do you write a shell script to enter commands in that subshell from the top level shell ?

```
FROM mongo

RUN mongo admin ???? db.createUser({ user: 'jsmith', pwd: 'some-initial-password', roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] });
```

The docker build process should display:

> Successfully added user: {
>       "user" : "jsmith",
>       "roles" : [
>           {
>               "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
>               "db" : "admin"
>           }
>       ]
>   }

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the way to add authetication via the Dockerfile.

- create a `init.js` file:

```
db = new Mongo().getDB("admin");

// create admin user

db.createUser({
  user: "admin",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [
    {
      role: "clusterAdmin",
      db: "admin"
    }
  ]
});


// create non admin user

db.createUser({
  user: "toto",
  pwd: "123",
  roles: [
    {
      role: "readWrite",
      db: "tube"
    }
  ]
});
```

- create the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

# init.js will be executed when the mongo instance runs

COPY ./init.js ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

- build your docker image

`docker build -t mongoAuth .`

- run the container (attached mode to see the logs)

`docker run --name mongoContainer -p 27017:27017 mongoAuth`

What I was missing was that I didn't set the database on which to create the users (admin database) by using:

`db = new Mongo().getDB("admin");`

Comment: The only thing missing is how to use environment variables in the mongo script to avoid setting values in clear  text.

Comment: The way to pass environment variables to a mongo shell script is to use the --eval flag. Example: ```mongo --eval "var myVar = '$MY_VAR' " myScript.js ```. To run this in a Dockerfile step, you need a running mongod process like this:
 ```RUN mongod& sleep 4; mongo --eval "var myVar = '$MY_VAR' " myScript.js ```